# Samba init scripts seem broken

Tags: 14.04, samba, samba4

The ntp init script for ntp for example works as expected, you can use `/etc/init.d/ntp` or `service ntp`

```
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/ntp stop
 * Stopping NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ]
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/ntp start
 * Starting NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ]
root@server:~# service ntp stop
 * Stopping NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ]
root@server:~# service ntp start
 * Starting NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ]
```

However smbd only works with service

```
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/smbd stop
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/smbd status
 * smbd is running
root@server:~# service smbd stop
smbd stop/waiting
root@server:~# service smbd status
smbd stop/waiting
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/smbd start
root@server:~# /etc/init.d/smbd status
 * smbd is not running
root@server:~# service smbd start
smbd start/running, process 2243
root@server:~# service smbd status
smbd start/running, process 2243
```

Also calling the service samba should call smbd and nmbd, but the status command works and the restart command doesn't do anyting.

Comment: Looks like the correct behaviour to me. The `/etc/init.d` method is supposed to be deprecated and no package has to make them work if they are using Upstart scripts.

Comment: Well, OK. But why leave the scripts in /etc/init.d/ if they are not working?

Comment: They are. Didn't the `status` command work? The `init.d` script for Samba has a line checking if Upstart is handling Samba, and refrains from interfering. It's the right thing to do from a package maintainer's point of view (make a single package work, whether or not Upstart is present).

Comment: OK, just saw that there is a `if init_is_upstart; then exit 1 fi`, makes sense.

Comment: That's because there's a `init.d` script for `samba`, which in turn calls other `init.d` scripts. (So `status` will work, other things won't.) If an Upstart script is not present but an `init.d` script is, the `service` command acts as an interface for them as well.

Comment: Yeah, saw that. This is my first server using upstart, always used Debian. Make an answer if you want the rep.

Comment: Coming from Debian `squeeze`, I suppose?

Comment: Last one I used was Wheezy (current) but updated from Squeeze, never had a fresh install. But upstart has never been the default in Debian AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, never the default. I mixed up a CentOS and a Debian server while checking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`samba` on Ubuntu (at least [10.04 onwards](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid-updates/amd64/samba/filelist)) supports Upstart for managing the `smbd` and related services. The `init.d` scripts are still present, but they check if Upstart is the `init`, and refrain from interfering with it if it is. Therefore the following `init.d` scripts are only useful for the `status`:

```
/etc/init.d/nmbd  # superseded by /etc/init/nmbd.conf
/etc/init.d/smbd  # superseded by /etc/init/smbd.conf
/etc/init.d/samba # if present
```

The `samba` script is a comparatively new entry, and has no Upstart equivalent.